# access to application properties (${appName}) in external configuration

Tags: grails

I've externalized my Grails configuration basically the same way as the config file suggests.
I've done it all the time with my 1.3 projects and the line

```
grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
```

in the external config worked great. Now I experience the problem with 2.0 that Grails seems not to be able to resolve the ${appName} - it will use [:] instead in redirects.

As soon as I move this line back to the internal configuration, everything works fine.

Is there any way to move this configuration line to the external configuration? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This has started happening for my app too during a recent migration.  The only thing that changed that I know of was going from tomcat 6 to tomcat 7.  Grails version is 1.3.7.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `${grails.util.Metadata.current.getApplicationName()}` instead.

Note that since `Metadata` implements `Map` you can't shorten that to `${grails.util.Metadata.current.applicationName}` since the key isn't `applicationName`.

Comment: @Ralf and Burt, thanks for this Q&A! It was surprisingly difficult to find this information.  The ${} didn't work for me (probably using them wrong.  Instead to name my log file I did this: 

    file: (System.properties.getProperty('catalina.base') ?: 'target') + '/logs/' + grails.util.Metadata.current.getApplicationName() +'.log'