# Grails redirecting to URL with appName as an empty map

Tags: url, grails, redirect, configuration

I'm having a weird issue with a Grails 2.2.3 application where any operation that requires a redirect is going to a URL like `http://localhost:8080/[:]/domain/show/1` instead of `http://localhost:8080/appName/domain/show/1`. Just navigating around works fine, but as soon as I do a domain operation like edit or create I get a redirect to a broken URL like the one above.

You would think that maybe I didn't have appName declared in my application.properties file, but I do (`app.name=mobilefaq`).

Does anyone know why this issue might be happening? If it helps, I also have the following config properties set as well:

```
grails.app.context = '/mobilefaq'
environments {
    development {
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
    }
    test {
        grails.serverURL = "http://testserver.company.com:8080/${appName}"
    }
}
```

Also note, this is when running the application on the test server specifically (the issue doesn't happen in development). I am doing `grails test war` to create the war as well, so it shouldn't be an issue where I'm deploying in the wrong environment.

Comment: How does the `redirect` look like? Do you have `absolute` property of redirect set to `true`?

Comment: Looks like the issue was actually `appName` not being resolved in an external config file, so grails.serverURL was getting set to `/[:]` instead of `/appName`. You must use `grails.util.Metadata.current.getApplicationName()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was actually in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632234/access-to-application-properties-appname-in-external-configuration) StackOverflow question. I will leave this for future help (if someone searches for something like "Grails URL empty map").