# Grails with external log4j with name "${appname}.log", it not work

Tags: grails, log4j, external

1.Grails version 2.5.1

i used Grails external log4j like this in env:

```
grails.config.locations = ["file:${basedir}/grails-app/config/log4j.groovy"]
```

and log4j.groovy like this

```
log4j = {
     appenders {
        appender new org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender(name:"dailyAppender",
                layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %l %c{3} %m%n'),fileName:"D:\\error-logs\\b2-error.log",datePattern:"'.'yyyy-MM-dd")
     }
     console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
     error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',      
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter',
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',       
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',         
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',         
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',  
            'org.springframework',
            'org.hibernate',
            'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
     debug  "grails.plugin.mail",
            "gsuk.sms",
            'grails.app.jobs',
            "gsuk.service"
        }
```

well,it error when the “=” in log4j.groovy

i don`t know why and how to make it work

by the way ,if i use it in config.groovy ,everything is ok ...

Comment: Have you tried to comment grails.config.locations, and put the content of log4j.groovy directly in Config.groovy in order to be sure that the problem is not in your log4j.groovy file ?

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar in my environment and it's working just fine. The difference may be that I have a log4j section in both my internal and external Config.groovy files. In my `\grails-app\conf\Config.groovy` file I have:

```
grails.config.locations = ["file:path\to\external-config.groovy"]
...
log4j.main = {...}
```

In my external-config.groovy I have:

```
log4j.external = {...}
```

This allows me to have both an base log4j definition used in my application at all times and then an external one I can append to the internal one. You just have to name them something differently, doesn't have to be `.main` or `.external`, it could be `.foo` and `.bar`.

Answer (score 0):

`${appName}` does not work in external config files, at least in Grails2. Use `grails.util.Metadata.current.getApplicationName()` (in or out of `${}`). See: [access to application properties (${appName}) in external configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632234/access-to-application-properties-appname-in-external-configuration)

Although I don't see `appName` anywhere in your example log4j code.